# Flyway integration(Enterprise Version) in Spring Boot problem

Tags: spring-boot, flyway

**Hello i got this error when i use flyway enterprise in my springboot project:**

```
16:27:46 WARN  o.s.b.w.s.c.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.ProxyAsyncConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setConfigurers' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'springAsyncConfig': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'customAsyncExceptionHandler'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'customAsyncExceptionHandler': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'importHistoryRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'importHistoryRepository': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#31db34da' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#31db34da': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration': Unexpected exception during bean creation; nested exception is java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type org.flywaydb.core.api.callback.FlywayCallback not present
```

**Here is my pom.xml file:**

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.flywaydb.enterprise</groupId>
     <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
     <version>6.0.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 3):

Related to [this Issue](https://github.com/flyway/flyway/issues/2333) Flyway 6.x.x is not compatible with Spring Boot < 2.2.0.

So you got 2 Choices:

- Update Spring Boot to >= 2.2.0
- Use flyway 5.x.x

Hope this helps